# New page within chapter in iText

Tags: java, pdf, formatting, itext

I have a large chapter containing several sections. I need to split one section content to make it more pretty and readable. I tried to use setPageEmpty(false) and newPage() before expected page break but the page doesn't breaks:

```
Document doc = new Document();
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, new FileOutputStream(filename));
writer.setPageEvent(new PageEventHandler(doc));
doc.open();

Chapter chapter = new ChapterAutoNumber("Main info");
chapter.add(new Paragraph("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet", font));
writer.setPageEmpty(false);
itextDocument.newPage();
```

After this code I'm going on to fill the chapter content and finally I'm going to write:

```
doc.add(chapter);
```

But after first paragraph I need a page break. How to split section content? I use iText 5.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to use the `newPage()` method if you want to add a new page *inside* a `Chapter`. Take a look at the following snippet:

```
Chapter chapter = new ChapterAutoNumber("Main info");
chapter.add(p1);
document.newPage();
chapter.add(p2);
document.add(chapter);
```

What do you see?

You see a chapter being populated with objects `p1` and `p2`. Both objects, `p1` and `p2`, **aren't rendered** to the `document` **until the very last line**: `document.add(chapter);` Only when this line is triggered, `p1` is actually added to the `document` because the document isn't aware of what happens with the `chapter` before you add it.

This means that `document.newPage()` is triggered *before* `p1` is rendered, instead of *between* `p1` and `p2`.

To solve this, you need to use the `Chunk.NEXTPAGE` object:

```
Chapter chapter = new ChapterAutoNumber("Main info");
chapter.add(p1);
chapter.add(Chunk.NEXTPAGE);
chapter.add(p2);
document.add(chapter);
```

That special `Chunk` object is now part of the `chapter` object, and a new page will be triggered between `p1` and `p2`.

Comment: I see! Thank you very much for explanation and snippet

Comment: Can we make `Chunk.NEXTPAGE` to be landscape? Is it possible to have a page rotate in the new page?

Comment: @Blaise No, I don't think that's possible in iText 5 or earlier. We fixed this in iText 7.