# iText inserting manual page break in table

Tags: java, pdf, itext, itext7

I'm currently evaluating iText and have the following problem:

We output individual items in a table with group totals. At the end of a group there is a grand total in a separate row and the table should continue on the next page.

Is there a way to manually insert a page break into the table?

Comment: *"Is there a way to manually insert a page break into the table?"* - how about starting a new table there and adding first the first table, then a page break, then the next table.

Comment: Yes, I think this is the only solution at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

This post may give some ideas to solving your problem:

[New page within chapter in iText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41998669/new-page-within-chapter-in-itext)

The answer posted by Bruno Lowagie has this section of code that works for inserting new page in a chapter:

```
Chapter chapter = new ChapterAutoNumber("Main info");
chapter.add(p1);
chapter.add(Chunk.NEXTPAGE);
chapter.add(p2);
document.add(chapter);
```

Maybe you could try adding Chunk.NEXTPAGE to the table cell before the grand total row and see if it works...

Comment: Chapter and Chunk is iText5

Comment: did a little search online, for iText7 maybe you can try:new AreaBreak(AreaBreakType.NEXT_PAGE)

Comment: Document seems to bee the only class, where you can add a AreaBreak.